# How to indent to the current indent level fast in a white line? [ VIM ]

Tags: vim

I've set my tab equal to 4 space in .vimrc

And I met a trouble, that in some code with complex indent level, and if I want to went to the appropriate indent place, I have to press multiple times `Tab`.

e.g.

```
if condition_a:
    if not condition_b:
        if random.choice(xrange(100)) > 35:
            if user.property != 'master':
                |
                # Above | is where I want to fast indent to with tab

# Lots of else block ommited here.
```

I know with `>` I can indent static code.

But how could I indent to that `|` position fast with `Tab` when typing code(`insert mode`)?

Comment: Indent behavior depends on a lot of different settings as well as the language support for the language you're editing. What language are you working with here and what (if any) plugins have you installed to help you work with it?

Answer (score 1):

Just press:

```
S
```

or:

```
cc
```

to enter insert mode at the right position.

See `:help S` and `:help cc`.

Answer (score 1):

except for `S`, `cc`, suggested by romainl, you can also use `o` to create new line and switch to insert mode.

Also in insert mode, you can press `Ctrl-F` to "auto-indent" the current line.

In normal mode, you can press `==` to format current line.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is only the functionality of normal mode's `<`, `>` but in insert mode, then `Ctrl-T` is *one tab right* and `Ctrl-D` is *one tab left*.